# Como deixar itens de uma lista <li> em destaque, mudando a posição independente de onde aparecer

Tags: html, jquery

estou montando uma aplicação sem banco de dados e com json, estou utilizando uma lista `<ul><li></li></ul>` para exibir os itens, 
O que preciso é deixar alguns itens em destaque.
Ex.

aqui uma lista normal, como estou exibindo

```
<li>Item 1</li> 
<li>Item 2</li> 
<li>Item 3</li> 
<li>Item 4 (destaque)</li> 
<li>Item 5</li> 
<li>Item 6</li> 
<li>Item 7(destaque)</li> 
<li>Item 8</li>
```

Aqui a lista que desejo mostrar já alterada

```
<li>Item 4 (destaque)</li> 
<li>Item 7(destaque)</li> 
<li>Item 1</li> 
<li>Item 2</li> 
<li>Item 3</li> 
<li>Item 5</li> 
<li>Item 6</li> 
<li>Item 8</li>
```

Já pesquisei diversos filtros em Jquery, mas nenhum atende a minha necessidade.

Comment: Os que tem destaque aparecem sempre no topo ? E por que ordem ? E em que ordem aparecem os que não tem destaque ?

Comment: Qual o critério para uma LI estar em destaque?

Answer (score 0):

Se pretende mostrar os que tem destaques no topo então precisa de ordenação. Assumindo que parte apenas da informação que está no html, pode fazer a ordenação com o `sort` baseado no resultado que vem de um seletor JQuery.

Essa ordenação seria de acordo com os critérios que pretende, ordenando primeiro por destaque e de seguida por nome. Após isso basta mover os elementos no html para a posição ordenada.

Exemplo:

```js
$(".lista li").on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("destaque"); //alternar destaque no clique
  atualizaLista();
});

function atualizaLista(){
  let listaOrdenada = $(".lista li").sort((a,b) => {
    let a_destaque = a.classList.contains("destaque");
    let b_destaque = b.classList.contains("destaque");
    
    if (a_destaque == b_destaque) //se ambos com o mesmo destaque
      return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent); //ordenar pelo nome
    else //caso contrario 
      return a_destaque && !b_destaque ? -1 : 1; //ordenar pelo destaque
  });
  
  for (let i = 0; i < listaOrdenada.length; i++) {
      //mover o elemento no html para o sitio correto de acordo com a ordenação
      listaOrdenada[i].parentNode.appendChild(listaOrdenada[i]); 
  }
}
```

```css
.destaque {
  background-color:cyan;
}

.destaque:after {
  content:' (destaque)';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique nos items para destacar

<ul class="lista">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: É quase isso que preciso, para esclarecer, estou trabalhando com eventos e nos eventos existem alguns que quero deixar nos primeiros resultados, mas não consigo ordena-los por trabalhar com json. então preciso de um critério para que após a página carregada a ordenação e o destaque ocorra automaticamente e a lista seja atualizada mostrando os destaques nas primeiras posições. lógico que terei que implementar um banco de dados ou alguma outra forma de verificar e comparar quais serão os destaques. :/ vou trabalhar em cima deste exemplo e tentar fazer o que preciso.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva Não consegui perceber o que precisa de facto. Olhando para o código que tenho na resposta, o que não faz que precisa que faça ? Relembro que na minha resposta os destaque estão a aparecer em primeiro, quer estejam ou não em primeiro

Comment: @LeonardoSilva Como adendo, se trabalha com json e é com ele que está a mexer então coloque essa parte na pergunta incluindo o código que está a utilizar para fazer o que quer que seja que está a fazer. Aproveite e indique também qual o resultado pretendido e que logica utiliza para chegar ao resultado pretendido.